# Creating subqueries from a distinct select statement - oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I achieve this table?

[image]

Here are the tables

[image]

[image]

And here is the query that I have come-up but I'm still having some error

```
SELECT DISTINCT Table1.ID as T1_ID,
       (SELECT *
          from Table1.Location
         where Table1.ID = Table1.ID) as T1_Location,
       Table2.Location as T2_Location
  FROM Table1
 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2 = ID
```

Comment: Removed conflicting product tags, pls add the one back that you are actually using!

Comment: What type of data do you expect for `Table1.location`? 3 strings concatenated? An array like structure (if the dB supports it)?

Comment: What is your DBMS product? Oracle? Sql Server? Mysql?

Comment: This can be achieved (at least in MySQL) with `GROUP BY`, but it will result in the second column being a concatenated string with the locations from Table1.

Comment: this is on oracle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested in SQL Flow with Oracle, it seems works

```sql
SELECT table1.ID, GROUP_CONCAT(table1.Location), table2.Location FROM table2 INNER JOIN table1 ON table2.ID = table1.ID GROUP BY table1.ID
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a concatenated string is okay for the `Table1.Location` output, you can do something like:

```sql
SELECT t1.id, CONCAT(t1.location, '-'), t2.location
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
GROUP BY t1.id, t2.location
```

*Syntax may vary slightly depending on your RDBMS*

Answer (score -1):

You need an additional column to uniquely identify records on Table1, otherwise you won't have control over which record is matched, or you can sort alphabetical or maybe use ROW_NUMBER().  If you don't care which record is selected from table 1, the query bellow will do.

```
WITH tmpT1 AS (SELECT DISTINCT ID, Location FROM Table1)  
SELECT t1.ID AS T1_ID, t1.location AS T1_Location, t2.Location AS  T2_Location FROM Table2 AS t2 JOIN tmpT1 AS T1
ON t2.ID = T1.ID
```